# How do I get my Android app to communicate with the server over a VPN?

Tags: android, grails, client, vpn

I have an android application that talks to a server app running on grails (Groovy on Grails).

Android app basically establishes a connection with this address:

> url="http://192.168.2.53:8080/tma/majBtm/androidToDesktop";

It all works fine when both the server and the android phone are connected in the same lan network.

Now the problem arises when I want the phone to talk to the server while the phone is outside the local network (I need it to use edge).

I came across VPN networks which I think might help me out. (the server has dynamic IP)

So what i did was go to dyndns.com and created a new hostname and have the app successfully run on the server. The host I created was - tmagrails.dyndns.com

How do I make my phone connect to this network? What changes am I supposed to make in order to get things working? 
Also, I really want to know if this is the right approach. If not, is there any way to get things going for me?

Please advice.

Comment: You want to connect to your network or connect to the app? You said you can connect to your app via tmagrails.dyndns.com - what more do you need? If you want to secure communication between app and client, you can setup SSL certificate on your web app container.

Comment: Hmm.. I did some more research. Heres what I basically need. Since my server has a dynamic IP, the ip address in this link `code`url="http://192.168.2.53:8080/tma/majBtm/androidToDesktop";`code` keeps changing everytime. So I set up a host name using dyndns.com. Now when I replace 192.168.2.53 with tmagrails.dyndns-ip.com, it doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

First you need to set up [port forwarding](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Port_forwarding) so that port 8080 is forwarded to your 192.168.2.53 ip address. A google search on your router model should tell you how to do this. If you want to make your app more secure you will also need to look at [SSL and TLS](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) While this won't garantee your app is secure it will stop the network traffic to your app being easily read if you were to access it from an open wifi hotspot.